# Regular expression for extracting preceeding numbers with optional dots

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression.

**Text Example**

```
1 Match
1.1 Match
45.67.21234.3 Match
1 Does not match1
12. Does not match
```

The extracted/matching values shall be:

```
1
1.1
45.67.21234.31
```

These shall not match:

```
1 Does not match1 // no match because of an additional digit in the text
12. Does not match // no match because of the dot after 12
```

So far my regex looks like this:

```
(\d+\.)+\d
```

But this does not match the very first entry.

Comment: Can there be something else than a space directly before or after the match?

Comment: I guess by using `(\d+\.)+\d` you are forcing a dot to come after digit

Comment: @Thefourthbird No, one space is the one and only character.

Comment: Do you mean like this perhaps using an anchor for the start of the string? `^\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?!\S)(?!.*\d)` [test](https://regex101.com/r/i5sUE3/1/)

Comment: This look promising... I'll check this out.

Comment: I suggest `^\d+(\.\d+)?`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `(\d+\.)+\d` will not match the first entry because using the quantifier `+` it has to match at least 1 time a digit and a dot.

What you might do is use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and use a pattern to match digits followed by repeating matching a dot and digits zero or more times so you also match the first entry.

After the match, make sure that the digits are not followed by a non whitespace character. If there can not be any more digits following, you you could use an additional negative lookahead.

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?!\S)(?!.*\d)
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*(?!\\S)(?!.*\\d)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i5sUE3/1/)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits followed by a repeating pattern to match a dot and 1+ digits
- `(?!\S)` negative lookahead to check what is on the left is not a non-whitespace character
- `(?!.*\d)` Negative lookahead to check what is on the right does not contain a digit

Answer (score 1):

A possible regex you could use is:

```
^((\d+\.)*\d+) \D*$
```

Where the capture group 1 would hold your match.

**Explanation:**

```python
^              # Start of the String
 (             # Open capture group 1:
  (\d+\.)      #  One or more digits, followed by a dot
         *     #  Repeated 0 or more times
          \d+  #  Followed by 1 or more digits
 )             # Closing capture group 1
               # Followed by a space
   \D*         # Followed by 0 or more non-digits
$              # Followed by the end of the String
```

The `^` and `$` will make us look at the entire String. The `\D*` will make sure there aren't any digits in the substring after the space. And the `\d+` after the `(\d+\.)*` makes sure there is always a leading digit, with one or multiple `#.` before it (where `#` is a non-negative number).

To extract this value, you could use this regex with a `String.matches` and `.replaceFirst` like this:

```java
// TODO: Give proper method name
String test(String str){
  String regex = "^((\\d+\\.)*\\d+) \\D*$";
  if(str.matches(regex))
    return str.replaceFirst(regex, "$1");
    // The `$1` will leave just the match of the first capture group,
    // removing everything else we don't need
  else
    return null;
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##XU@xTsMwFNz7FU9WB7uhlpIWkKhgoWJj6ohBcpPX4uI6ke0UUJVvD46boMBi@53v7t0d5EnOD8VH2@ZaOgfPUpnzBKCqt1rl4Lz04TqVqoBj@KIbb5XZv7yCZB0NYFfaHgSPzj9Kh3AHBj9hoJ5JGmx9/k6ugKR8NCyv@c0tz9JsseSLEQfWJTowpQ87A5ZGMOP/YNKwmABg8@08HnlZe16FnV4bOmRJCMwfgCTd/AsytgrKZhKOvuCowdDGedtX7AGLe/yCeyBvlApRJEJwNuseDIRYz6ZkFdlqR4OUx4joaFSxIalFX1vTeXOLlZY5PikbdkZWaDlNCbvYoHb4V2RqrS@5m7b9AQ)

If a single number without any spaces behind it (i.e. `"123"`) should match as well, a minor modification can be made to the regex by changing `\\D*$` to `( \\D*)?$` so the space becomes optional.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##XU@xTsMwFNz7FU9WB7uhlpIUkKiAgYqNqSMGySSvJcV1ItspoCrfHhwnQYHF9jvf3bs7yJNcHvKPts2UtBaeZKHPM4CqflNFBtZJ569TWeRw9F9060yh988vIFlHA9iVZgDBoXUP0iLcgMZPGKlnEntbl72TCyAxnwyrS351zZM4SVc8nXBgU6IFXTq/02NxABP@D@7RlDQsBAHYfluHR17Wjld@tVOajpEiAss7IFE3/4KMrb2ymflj6DkpMpayzgxNB8DgHr/gFsgrpULkkRCcLboHoyDEZsHu52QdBMWOejUPYdHSIGRjWIOuNrqz5wYrJTN8LIxfG1i@2TwmrLdBZfGvSNdK9dGbtv0B)

Answer (score 0):

We can try using the following regex pattern against each line:

```
^(?!\D*\d[^0-9.]+\d).*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\\s|$).*$
```

Explanation:

```
^                            from the start of the line
    (?!\D*\d[^0-9.]+\d)      assert that two (or more) separate numbers
                             do not occur in the line
    .*                       then consume anything, up to
    \b\d+(?:\.\d+)?          an integer, or complete decimal
    (?=\\s|$)                where either a space or the end of the line follows
    .*                       then consume anything, up to
$                            the end of the line
```

Here is a Java code using this pattern:

```
String line = "45.67.21234.3";
String pattern = "^(?!\\D*\\d[^0-9.]+\\d).*\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=\\s|$).*$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
else {
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```

I have tested it against all your inputs and it seems to be working.